# Como filtrar as linhas se a coluna está sem nome de variável - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho alguns dados em excel que importei para um dataframe em Python (`Base_Eventos`). Preciso sumarizar uma variável (`idPartida`), então uso:

```
Base_Eventos.groupby (by = 'idPartida '). count()
```

Só que o resultado sai com a coluna do contador sem um nome de variável. E vou precisar usar essa saída de contagem para fazer um filtro. base ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A segunda coluna está em branco (nome da variável).
É possível adicionar um nome?
Ou há outra forma de filtrar sem precisar adicionar um nome.
Pois quero selecionar os `idPartida` com mais de 1000 eventos.

Comment: Vc pode colocar o Base_Eventos.head() no seu post?